# Screen share app goes black when turning scaling on

Tags: screen-sharing

When I turn scaling on for Screen Share the window just goes black. If I turn scaling off it stays black. I have to disconnect and reconnect to get the screen back, but then scaling is turned off again. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: black screen with scaling turned on]

- Host is Mac Mini running macOS 10.11.6 (15G18013)
- Guest is Macbook Pro running macOS 10.13.4 (17E202)

Comment: Have you tried saving the connection set correctly, then launching it from that, rather than swapping the scaling once it's active? tbh, It's not an issue i've seen before & I remote from 10.13 to 10.11 often]

Comment: Do you mean if I save the connection as a .vncloc? If so, then yes. I still see the same problem.

Comment: Only thing I can think then is something to do with the screen resolutions of each. I remote into El Cap [& HS] machines all day from High Sierra & I can't repro this at all, sorry.